# Ethereum event logs equivalent for EOS

Tags: smart-contract, ram, bandwidth, cpu, ethereum

One of the solutions for saving quite a lot data in Ethereum Smart contracts is to log data by emitting event, which saves our gas. Is EOS quite similar? Does it provide us with the very same opportunity like Ethereum logging to save our RAM? if yes.. how many µs of CPU bandwidth this simple log function (without any additional functionality) will take? Will it take any RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to log events on chain, you can use the demux-js library on the eosio repo to listen to chain events.  From here, you can store that data as it updates in your database of choice.